# replace transform 1 term on 1 side of equation in manim

Tags: manim

i have an equation of the form

f(a,f(b,z)) = f(f(a,b),z)

and I want to change it to

f(a,f(b,z)) = f(c,z)

all posts about this type of question suggested to break the equation into different parts and then use replace transform on only the 'f(a,b)' part. so i did:

```
class TransformEquation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        myTemplate = TexTemplate()
        myTemplate.add_to_preamble(r"\usepackage[inference]{semantic}")

        variables = VGroup(MathTex("a"), MathTex("b"), MathTex("c")).arrange_submobjects().shift(DOWN*2)
        premise = MathTex(r"f(X,f(Y,Z)) = f(f(X,Y),Z) \ \ \ \ f(a,b) = c")
        self.play(premise.animate.shift(UP*0.5))
        under = Underline(premise)
        self.play(Create(under))

        eq1 = MathTex("f({{X}},f({{Y}},{{Z}}))", "=", "f(", "f({{X}},{{Y}}),", "{{Z}})").next_to(premise, DOWN, buff=0.5)
        eq2 = MathTex("f({{a}},f({{b}},{{Z}}))", "=", "f(", "f({{a}},{{b}}),", "{{Z}})").next_to(premise, DOWN, buff=0.5)
        eq3 = MathTex("f({{a}},f({{b}},{{Z}}))", "=", "f(", "{{c}},", "{{Z}})").next_to(premise, DOWN, buff=0.5)

        self.play(Write(eq1))
        self.wait(0.5)
        self.play(TransformMatchingTex(Group(eq1, variables), eq2))
        self.wait(0.5)
        self.play(ReplacementTransform(eq2[-2], eq3[-2]))
```

but it doesnt work, it only moves like a bracket around.. what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ReplacementTransform` you can just use `TransformMatchingTex` again on `eq2` and `eq3`.

```py
from manim import *

class TransformEquation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        myTemplate = TexTemplate()
        myTemplate.add_to_preamble(r"\usepackage[inference]{semantic}")

        variables = VGroup(MathTex("a"), MathTex("b"), MathTex("c")).arrange_submobjects().shift(DOWN*2)
        premise = MathTex(r"f(X,f(Y,Z)) = f(f(X,Y),Z) \ \ \ \ f(a,b) = c")
        self.play(premise.animate.shift(UP*0.5))
        under = Underline(premise)
        self.play(Create(under))

        eq1 = MathTex("f({{X}},f({{Y}},{{Z}}))", "=", "f(", "f({{X}},{{Y}}),", "{{Z}})").next_to(premise, DOWN, buff=0.5)
        eq2 = MathTex("f({{a}},f({{b}},{{Z}}))", "=", "f(", "f({{a}},{{b}}),", "{{Z}})").next_to(premise, DOWN, buff=0.5)
        eq3 = MathTex("f({{a}},f({{b}},{{Z}}))", "=", "f(", "{{c}},", "{{Z}})").next_to(premise, DOWN, buff=0.5)

        self.play(Write(eq1))
        self.wait(0.5)
        self.play(TransformMatchingTex(Group(eq1, variables), eq2))
        self.wait(0.5)
        self.play(TransformMatchingTex(eq2, eq3))
```

Last frame:

[image]